# Save generated pdf to mysql database using phpword

Tags: php, mysql, phpword

I'm trying to save the generated pdf to lacation in the database using phpword, but it does not save it properly.
Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'Word');
$templateProcessor->saveAS($temp_file);

$domPdfPath = realpath(PHPWORD_BASE_DIR . 'dompdf/dompdf');
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($domPdfPath);
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');

$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($temp_file); 
$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord , 'PDF');
$xmlWriter->save('result.pdf');  

//Save it
$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord , 'PDF');
$result = $xmlWriter->save('result.pdf'); 

$pdf = $result;


mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Error Connect to Database");
mysql_select_db("word");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO invoice (id,location) VALUES ('', '$pdf')") ;
```

Comment: What is the runtime value of `$pdf`?  How does this fail?  What does `mysql_error()` tell you after you execute the query?

Comment: It does not tell me anything. a new record is added where id field is filled and location field is empty.

Comment: And what is the value of `$pdf`?  What specific data did `save()` return?  What is the data type of the `location` field in the DB?  How are you observing it?  What specifically are you expecting to be there?

Comment: $pdf generates a result.pdf file in folder. i want to store the location of this file in the 'location' field. For example 'result.pdf'. the location field is a varchar(255) in the database.

Comment: Wouldn't the path just be the combination of `$domPdfPath . 'result.pdf'`, or something along those lines?  It sounds like `save()` isn't returning what you expect it to, and I'm not seeing where it's documented otherwise.  But your code already defines the path *used* by PdfWord, so just save that same path.

Comment: $domPdfPath is the pad of domPdf library. But can you give me an exaple of how to write it?